# Need to import from a data xml file to oracle sql developer and for creating Table

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

as i said in the title, i would like to import data from a xml file to oracle sql developer for creating a table, but it failed.

Here is my code :

```
drop table cata;

create table cata(
filename VARCHAR2(32) primary key,
xml xmltype
);

create or replace directory xml_dir as 'C:\Users\pierr\Documents\sqldeveloper';

insert into cata values (
'cata.xml', XMLTYPE(BFILENAME('XML_DIR', 'cata.xml'),nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')));
```

And the compiler tell me this type of error :

> ORA-22288: FILEOPEN operation failed on file or LOB Data invalid.

But my xml file seems good, so I don't see how to resolve this

Here my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tylor</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Gary More</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Virgin redords</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Eros</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>One night only</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1998</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.10</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1973</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.50</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Romanza</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Black angel</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1999</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>For the good times</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1971</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Stop</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>T`Pau</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1991</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Red</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>London</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: Hello Pierre, welcome to StackOverflow. Have you try to reduce your XML file keeping only one <CD> element to see if the error is already there and to reduce your source file on StackOverflow and to avoid to waste time of user. Is your directoryname correct because I see that your name is "Pierre" but the directory name is with "pierr". What happens if you change nls-charset-id from UTF8 to ISO-8859-1 or if you change encoding in XML file to 'UTF-8' ? Can you give us more information ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the oracle database server is not installed on your Windows machine.  Your directory object definition is referencing your local machine folder.  Oracle knows nothing about your local client.  You have to create the directory object pointing to a location on the database sever, then copy the file to that location on the server.

From the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5008.htm#SQLRF01207):

"A directory object specifies an alias for a directory on the server file system ...  Oracle Database does not verify that the directory you specify actually exists. Therefore, take care that you specify a valid directory in your operating system."

Comment: Yes it is the problem, i resolved it .

Even if my xml file was put well in the local directory, it didn't recognize it .

So i put it in the sub repository oradata and it works well

Answer (score 0):

The XML appears to be valid so if there is an issue it is with the directory or when you load it from the file.

You can do it in PL/SQL; you just have to manually break the XML file up into 4000 byte/character chunks:

```sql
DECLARE
  xml CLOB;
BEGIN
  xml := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tylor</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>' || '
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Gary More</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Virgin redords</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Eros</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
  </CD>' || '
  <CD>
    <TITLE>One night only</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1998</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.10</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1973</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.50</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
  </CD>' || '
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Romanza</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Black angel</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1999</YEAR>
  </CD>' || '
  <CD>
    <TITLE>For the good times</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1971</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
  </CD>' || '
  <CD>
    <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Stop</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>T`Pau</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
  </CD>' || '
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1991</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>' || '
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Red</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>London</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>';

  INSERT INTO cata (
    filename,
    xml
  ) VALUES (
    'cata.xml',
    XMLTYPE( xml )
  );
END;
/
```

Then you can select from the table:

```sql
SELECT x.*
FROM   cata c
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/CATALOG/CD'
         PASSING c.xml
         COLUMNS
         title VARCHAR2(50) PATH './TITLE',
         artist VARCHAR2(50) PATH './ARTIST',
         country VARCHAR2(5) PATH './COUNTRY',
         company VARCHAR2(20) PATH './COMPANY',
         price   NUMBER(6,2)  PATH './PRICE',
         year    NUMBER(4,0)  PATH './YEAR'
       ) x
```

outputs:

> ```
> TITLE                    | ARTIST            | COUNTRY | COMPANY        | PRICE | YEAR
> :----------------------- | :---------------- | :------ | :------------- | ----: | ---:
> Empire Burlesque         | Bob Dylan         | USA     | Columbia       |  10.9 | 1985
> Hide your heart          | Bonnie Tylor      | UK      | CBS Records    |   9.9 | 1988
> Greatest Hits            | Dolly Parton      | USA     | RCA            |   9.9 | 1982
> Still got the blues      | Gary More         | UK      | Virgin redords |  10.2 | 1990
> Eros                     | Eros Ramazzotti   | EU      | BMG            |   9.9 | 1997
> One night only           | Bee Gees          | UK      | Polydor        |  10.9 | 1998
> Sylvias Mother           | Dr.Hook           | UK      | CBS            |   8.1 | 1973
> Maggie May               | Rod Stewart       | UK      | Pickwick       |   8.5 | 1990
> Romanza                  | Andrea Bocelli    | EU      | Polydor        |  10.8 | 1996
> When a man loves a woman | Percy Sledge      | USA     | Atlantic       |   8.7 | 1987
> Black angel              | Savage Rose       | EU      | Mega           |  10.9 | 1995
> 1999 Grammy Nominees     | Many              | USA     | Grammy         |  10.2 | 1999
> For the good times       | Kenny Rogers      | UK      | Mucik Master   |   8.7 | 1995
> Big Willie style         | Will Smith        | USA     | Columbia       |   9.9 | 1997
> Tupelo Honey             | Van Morrison      | UK      | Polydor        |   8.2 | 1971
> Soulsville               | Jorn Hoel         | Norwa   | WEA            |   7.9 | 1996
> The very best of         | Cat Stevens       | UK      | Island         |   8.9 | 1990
> Stop                     | Sam Brown         | UK      | A and M        |   8.9 | 1988
> Bridge of Spies          | T`Pau             | UK      | Siren          |   7.9 | 1987
> Private Dancer           | Tina Turner       | UK      | Capitol        |   8.9 | 1983
> Midt om natten           | Kim Larsen        | EU      | Medley         |   7.8 | 1983
> Pavarotti Gala Concert   | Luciano Pavarotti | UK      | DECCA          |   9.9 | 1991
> The dock of the bay      | Otis Redding      | USA     | Atlantic       |   7.9 | 1987
> Picture book             | Simply Red        | EU      | Elektra        |   7.2 | 1985
> Red                      | The Communards    | UK      | London         |   7.8 | 1987
> Unchain my heart         | Joe Cocker        | USA     | EMI            |   8.2 | 1987
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b4cd8ecfe3cb79da2861cc40d18ac344)*